# Problem with Salesforce as Service Provider (SP) and other system as Identity Provider (.PEM certificate)

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

I am trying to implement single sign on (SSO) with my client, using SAML 2.0.

My client has an application in "Outsystems", "Outsystems" will act as Identity Provider (IdP) and Salesforce as Service Provider (SP).

Outsystems returns a ".pem" certificate, I load this certificate in Salesforce, but we have this error when doing a SAML validation in Salesforce.

[image]

**Does salesforce accept certificates with extension ".pem"?**

I have tried making a connection with Axiom (https://axiomsso.herokuapp.com/Home.action), and Axiom returns an Identity Provider certificate with a ".crt" extension. And with AXIOM I have managed to perform the SSO without problems.

Salesforce only accept ".crt" certificates? Should I convert my client ".pem" certificate to ".crt"?

Any clue could help us. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll leave the answer here, in case that helps anyone.

We met with Salesforce support, the response we got was that salesforce does NOT support identity provider certificates with a ".pem" extension.

Solution: Salesforce gave us these articles to transform the ".pem" certificate into "JKS" so that salesforce is able to process it:

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000381987&type=1

https://www.baeldung.com/convert-pem-to-jks

https://www.learninjava.com/convert-p12-to-jks-and-pem-to-jks/